# Android: How to calculate height from which device is fall down using accelerometer?

Tags: java, android

I have trying to calculate height from which device is fall down  using accelerometer sensor but no luck.

I could able to detect the device fall.

Please share thoughts or workaround for the ask if any of you tried the same.

Below is code i tried.

'private void handleSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

```
        double gvt=SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY;

        //int sensor=event.sensor.getType();
        double xx=event.values[0];
        double yy=event.values[1];
        double zz=event.values[2];

        double aaa=Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
                                        +Math.pow(yy, 2)
                                        +Math.pow(zz, 2)));




        if (aaa<=6.0) {
          min=true;
          mintime=System.currentTimeMillis();
          minXx = zz;

          Log.d(TAG,"Min: xx, yy, zz = "+xx+", "+yy+", "+zz);
        }

        if (min==true) {
            acc+=aaa;
            count++;
          i++;
          if(aaa>=13.5) {
            max=true;
            maxtime = System.currentTimeMillis();               
            maxXx = zz;
            Log.d(TAG,"Max: xx, yy, zz = "+xx+", "+yy+", "+zz);
          }
        }

        if (min==true && max==true) {
            double time = (maxtime - mintime);
            //double distance = (minXx-maxXx)* Math.pow(time,2)/1000;
            double maxVelocity = (aaa/count)*time;
            double avgVelocity = maxVelocity/2;
            double distance = (avgVelocity * time)/1000;

            String msg = "FALL DETECTED!!!!! Duration = "+time + " milli secs, distance = "+ distance +" cms mtrs";
          Toast.makeText(this, msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.d(TAG, msg);
          v.vibrate(75);
          resetValues();
        }

        if (i>4) {
            resetValues();
        }
      }

}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried already, and outline what is not working as you would like.

Comment: @dharms,  I have added the code, please help me if you know.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer gives you changes in velocity. This can include the sudden stop at the end of the fall. There are techniques to use such data to figure out traversal. Here's some reading material:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system

However a consumer grade device designed for the interpretation of basic gestures is not going to be accurate, and you'll have false positives and false negatives because it will be hard to distinguish such motions from other things that can happen to the device. So manage your expectations.

Comment: I need to agree with you, I add to use the accelerometer to start a service if the device start moving, after trying a lot of algorithm, I find out that even resting on a desk, some accelerometer catch a lot of false positive. So you need an algo to "correct" the values, can't remember the name of this algo... using an alpha value from 0 to 1. (if someone can help)